# Encoding iso-8859-1 isn't working on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically project is upgraded from ruby 1.8 to ruby 2.5.

ISO-8859-1 encoding is declared on pages which works fine in previous ruby and rails version.

Also method is written in application controller.

```
  before_action :set_charset

  def set_charset
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  end
```

application layout is declared like following.

```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

but in **ruby 2.5** at javascript_tag it gives following error.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError
"\xA3" on UTF-8
```

Tried following options at rails level but it won't work.

application.rb

```
   config.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
   config.force_encoding = "UTF-8"
```

Comment: I think you need to do force_encoding, wherever you need to do it

Comment: Tried force_encoding, still receiving the error

Comment: Removed old js from application, then it start working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all old js files from application. It started running.